# How to Consume SAP WSDL services in Objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, wsdl

To use WSDL services I am referring the code from http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/wiki/UsageInstructions. My code is

```
  ZESRV_PM_SEARCH_PARAMETERS *binding = [[ZESRV_PM_SEARCH_PARAMETERS alloc] initWithAddress:urlString]; 
   binding.logXMLInOut = YES;
   binding.authUsername = username; 
   binding.authPassword = password;
   
   
   NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   [array addObject:@"Karama"];
   [array addObject:@"Commercial"];
   [array addObject:@"Industrial"];

   
   ZESRV_PM_SEARCH_PARAMETERSSvc_TableOfZesrvLocation *request = [[ZESRV_PM_SEARCH_PARAMETERSSvc_TableOfZesrvLocation alloc] init];
   
   request.item=array;
   
   ZESRV_PM_SEARCH_PARAMETERSResponse *response = [binding ZesrvPmSearchParametersUsingParameters:request];
   NSLog(@"response %@",response);

   NSError * responseError = response.error;
   
   NSLog(@"responseError %@",responseError);

   NSArray *array=response.bodyparts;

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       [self processResponse:response];
   });
```

Here I am getting the response as <ZESRV_PM_SEARCH_PARAMETERSResponse: 0x68040d0> and response error is Null. But I am getting response.bodypart also NULL. Why response bodyparts getting Null?

Can anybody help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used wsdl2Objc as i write my own code for this. But [wsdl2code](http://www.wsdl2code.com/pages/home.aspx) is a more better library for working with Soap.